# Js setInterval on each table row with different time count

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, setinterval

I have a table and on each row I want to run timer according to different max count number for each row.

```
<tr>
    <td class='timer' data-maxTime='10'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class='timer' data-maxTime='20'></td>
</tr>

<script>

    $(".timer").each(function(){
                    
        var count = $(this).attr("data-maxTime");
        runTimer($(this),count); 

    });
    
    
    function runTimer(ele,count){
        
        interval = setInterval(function() { 

            timer = count.split(':');

            minutes = parseInt(timer[0], 10);
            seconds = parseInt(timer[1], 10);
            --seconds;
            minutes = (seconds < 0) ? --minutes : minutes;
            
            if (minutes < 0) {
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
            seconds = (seconds < 0) ? 59 : seconds;
            seconds = (seconds < 10) ? '0' + seconds : seconds;

            if(minutes > -1){
                ele.html(minutes + ':' + seconds);
                rideTime = minutes + ':' + seconds;
            }
        },1000);
        
    }
    
</script>
```

Timer is running for each case , but there is a delay of 1 second for each row. Can anyone please suggest, how these timers start exactly at same time ?

Comment: This makes no sense: `var counter = setInterval(runTimer($(this),count), 1000);` You are calling runTimer and setting what it returns to the setInterval.

Comment: @epascarello I have edited by question

Comment: Next issue `timer = count.split(':');` count is never updated so not sure how it would count down.

Answer (score 0):

The problem most probably lies in your `runTimer` function, because you are assigning the result of `setInterval` to an undefined variable (`interval`), which will become a global variable. When you call `runTimer` for the second time, you are actually overwriting that global variable.

Try defining your `interval` variable first.